# Sometimes invoking a script that has `#!/usr/bin/env bash` opens bashdb instead

Tags: bash, debugger

I’ve seen this infrequently and unpredictably for years. Today it happened on a Mac, trying to run my script that checks for MacPorts updates that should have run as a cronjob but seemed to have been missed.

Running the script at the Bash prompt opens `bashdb` instead. Explicitly invoking bash to run the script works as expected. Running (at least some) other scripts at the bash prompt runs the scripts as expected.  Running `/usr/bin/env bash` opens a new instance of bash.

- macOS High Sierra 10.13.1 (17B48)
- MacPorts 2.4.2
- MacPorts bash @4.4.12_0
- MacPorts bashdb @4.4-0.94_0

I’ve been hacking on my Bash configuration for decades, so there’s far too much to dump in here, but `bashdb` is not mentioned in my bash startup scripts, `~/bin`, `alias`, or `set`/`env`/`printenv`.

**What would I have done to make this happen on purpose? And how do I undo it?**

Comment: Do you have `set -x` somewhere?

Comment: What is the `#!` line at the start of your script?

Comment: grep doesn't find it in my startup scripts or in ~/bin.  From a quick search I don't see any indication that `set -x` should invoke `bashdb`.

Comment: @DavidPostill it's in the question... `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Comment: Hmm. Have you checked `alias`?

Comment: My gut feeling is that `bashdb` is to blame. Perhaps it hijacks the parsing of shebang and this is how it calls itself? Hard to believe this would happen on Linux, since there Kernel is responsible for parsing, and it would be hard to hijack it, but I don't know how this works on Mac, maybe there it's doable from userspace.

Comment: @DavidPostill what should I check for in `alias`?  There's no mention of `bashdb`.